# How to add a New file (without extension) to 'New' Context Menu in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu

I want to add `New File` without an extension [`.`] to the `New` context menu in Windows and have already tried the well-known method, which does not work when creating key `HKCR\.`:

- Create Registry key `HKCR\.\ShellNew`, with `REG_SZ` value `NullFile` inside it

Any ideas my friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of works, provided the file is named immediately after creation:

- This `no-extension.reg` adds `Text Document` with a non-default icon to the `New` context menu, which creates a new plain text file [`.new`] with the whole name being highlighted within Explorer since there is no name before the extension:

  ```reg
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]
  @="txtfile"
  "Content Type"="text/plain"
  "PerceivedType"="text"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\OpenWithProgids]
  "VSCode.txt"=""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\PersistentHandler]
  @="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\ShellNew]
  "ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,34,00,37,00,30,00,00,00
  "NullFile"=""
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add 'New File' without extension (.) to 'New' content menu
> in Windows.

Context for this normally associates a file by its extension. No extension means the operating system cannot associate. So your registry method is not going to work.

There is not a native Windows way to use contexts for file operations without extensions.

Comment: If no extension, an operating system has no way to figure if out, so it is not possible.

Comment: Not the Operatign System... Explorer (which is also the Windows desktop, not just the filemanager) can't figure it out. Microsoft decided many years ago to make the extension the identifying mark of the file-content. Other operating Systems have no issue at all because they don't rely on the extension at all. They store separate meta-data for each file (e.g MacOS) or they probe the file content itself to identify what it is (e.g Linux and many other Unix systems).